# Why does `dd` have `swab` functionality

Tags: dd, history

The manpage for `dd` notes an option `swab`

```
swab   swap every pair of input bytes
```

Why?

---

Don't ask me what I'm trying to do -- I'm not doing anything in particular, I'm just scratching my head.   If were going to offer swaps, why not do it for all word sizes?   Not that I need that, but if we're just swapping 2 neighboring bytes it must be tied to a specific hardware scenario. Why not document that in the manual or `info`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because that was its original purpose. In the words of [Douglas McIlroy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Douglas_McIlroy), who was the head of the team that created Unix, in [*A Research UNIX Reader: Annotated Excerpts from the Programmer’s Manual, 1971-1986*](https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/%7Edoug/reader.pdf):

> DD (v5 page 74)
>
> Originally intended for converting files between the ASCII, little-endian, byte-stream world of DEC computers and the EBCDIC, big-endian, blocked world of IBM, dd was endowed with an appropriately bastard syntax (Thompson, v5). Pike has noted a cultural quirk. Much as families perpetuate the quaint sayings of children, users are wont to invoke *dd* with the JCL-ish formula, `dd if=input of=output`, or perhaps with `cat input | dd of=output`, but rarely with the elementary utterance `dd <input >output`.

“v5 page 74” refers to the [Unix v5 manual](https://www.tuhs.org/Archive/Distributions/Research/Dennis_v5/v5man) (p.51 of this PDF). The [corresponding source code](https://minnie.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=V5/usr/source/s1/dd.c) is also online.

[EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) was a character encoding¹ used on IBM machines. It was as important as [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) at the time. Both ASCII and EBCDIC encode a character in an 8-bit byte. Both IBM and DEC machines had 16-bit words. (Actually there were other word sizes, especially 18 and 36, but `dd` was written with 16-bit words in mind.) A modern analog of that purpose would be using [iconv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconv).

The original purpose of `dd` stopped mattering fairly quickly: it became a way to copy binary data block by block, especially to or from tape drives which can't be accessed byte by byte. For that matter, `dd` is mostly irrelevant today: `dd` was useful on old unices where tools such as `cat`, `head` and `tail` only worked on text files (they processed data line by line, so a line had to fit in a small amount of memory, and they didn't support null bytes), but on modern unices these tools usually support binary files.

In any case, no one found it useful to extend `dd` to other endianness change scenario. Part of the reason for this is that as computers became more common, it became more common for data formats to be defined in a machine-independent way. Although endianness conversion is still necessary now and then today, there's rarely a use for it on a whole file: usually only parts of the data are word-oriented, and other parts are byte-oriented and need to stay as they were.

¹  <sub>Or rather a family of encodings, but that's not relevant here.</sub>

Comment: so any idea why is it not removed from modern `dd`?   Code needs to be continually maintained and tested

Comment: `dd` is a rat-bag of options, but it will create sparse files, convert case of all characters, and splice changes into a file. Rather too hands-on now, but formerly very useful.

Comment: See also:  The "NUXI Problem" - http://catb.org/jargon/html/N/NUXI-problem.html

Comment: When did `cat` only work on text files, and process them line by line? It never did so. And `tail` also did support blocks and characters since its very beginning.

Comment: For reference, here’s [V7 `cat`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7/usr/src/cmd/cat.c) (which loops using `getc` and `putchar`) and [V5 `cat`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V5/usr/source/s1/cat.s) (which loops using `read` and `write` on 512-byte buffers). No line-by-line handling there...

Comment: @ktzap Not on all unix variants. It was a long time ago and I don't remember where, but I've definitely encountered implementations that didn't support binary files. Probably ~1990 vintage.

Comment: I find it highly doubtful that that ever were the case. Maybe some "Unix-like" environment running on MSDOS (after all, `command.com` did support "pipes" using temporary files, LOL). Until you remember it, I'll consider that claim baseless.

Comment: @Gilles: Reminds me of command.com's `type` builtin, which treats 0x1A (Ctrl+Z) as the "end of file" in imitation of CP/M, or the `copy` builtin, which has /a (text) and /b (binary) options for the same reason....

Comment: @ktzap for that matters, from TUHS, `cat` was written in assembler up until v6 and rewritten in C using stdio in v7, but in any case, it was never line based back then. `head`/`tail` didn't exist yet in V5.

Comment: In particular, `swab` was used for converting PDP-11 4-byte integers in its so-called "middle-endian" format into big-endian. The convention on a PDP-11 was to store  0x0A0B0C0D as the 4 byte sequence 0x0B 0x0A 0x0D 0x0C.

Comment: Okay, I spent a few minutes reading this post, and kept wondering why the option was named `swab` -- since it's purpose  was **swap** bytes.  So... why wasn't the option called `swap` and.... was it some sort of inside joke to "invert" the last letter of `swap`??

Comment: @MarkStewart My guess: Unix mainly ran on PDP-11's at the time, and the PDP-11 assembly instruction to swap bytes was named [swab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PDP-11_architecture#Single-operand_instructions).